# Brave Browser crashed on start

Tags: macos, crash, brave, brave-browser

On a M1 Mac the Brave Browser quits after a few seconds right after startup.

MacOs: Version 12.4
Brave: Version 1.40.105 Chromium: 103.0.5060.53 (Offizieller Build) (arm64)

What can i do do fix this problem?

Answer (score -1):

One workaround is to delete the Preferences file:

```
~Library/Application Support/BraveSoftware/Brave-Browser/Default/Preferences
```

To Navigate to ~Library: Open Finder, hold 'option' and click in menu on 'go to'